# Url Masking Dropbox With Cname or Httaccess

Tags: .htaccess, dropbox, dropbox-api, cloudflare, cname

I want to Use dropbox download links with my custom domain.
example: dropbox file download URL - https://www.dropbox.com/s/ABCD/filename?dl=1

It's returning direct download that's fine. I want to do with https://mydomain/s/ABCD/filename?dl=1. Where ABCD will be dynamic.

Is This Possible?

Comment: Since you added htaccess tag, so it means you are looking for htacces rules here? Please share your current htaccess rules if you have one in your question.

Comment: I am looking for htaccess rule.  Can you share?

Comment: You will have to enable and use `mod_proxy` for this.

Answer (score 0):

***EDIT:*** In case you want to hit URL `http://yourdomain/s/filename/dl=1`(as per samples only) and which should be served by backend url http://dropbox then try following.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)mydomain(?:\.com)?$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/s/[\w-]+/?$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^dl=1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.dropbox.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,QSA,L]
```

---

---

This assumes that we want to hit `http://dropbox.com/` which should be served by `http://yourdomain/` Based on your shown samples, could you please try following. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing these URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)dropbox\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mydomain%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,QSA,L]
```